# Checking grains out of list with saltstack

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I want to check if a specific version of a program is already installed.
Therefore, I got a state file:

```
{% set rvs = ['1113','1278'] %}

{% for rv in rvs %}

{% if ('r{{ rv }}' not in grains.get('cat12', [])) %}

... install it ...

{% else %}

... do nothing ...

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

In my grains I have:

```
cat12:
  - r1113
```

I would expect that '1278' is installed and list item '1113' triggers nothing, but even that is installed again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such syntax as using `{{` and `}}` inside `{%` and `%}`. What's inside `{%` and `%}` is already Jinja. Just concatenate the string literal and the string variable with the `~` operator.

```
{% if 'r' ~ rv not in grains.get('cat12', []) %}
```

Or you can use the format filter:

```
{% if 'r%s'|format(rv) not in grains.get('cat12', []) %}
```